# Linking Named-Entity Recognition tagged files to Google maps using Google Geocoding API

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, geocoding, named-entity-recognition

I have text files which are tagged using NER and I need to link them to a Google map.

```
<p>Gardai|NNP|O fear|VBP|O a|DT|O 28-year-old|JJ|O man|NN|O ,|,|O missing|VBG|O from|IN|O his|PRP$|O Dublin|NNP|I-PER home|NN|O for|IN|O a|DT|I-DAT week|NN|I-DAT
```

Although locations are not tagged correctly ie. Dublin is tagged as a person, I want to use the Google Geocoding API, to feed in the location which is identified as being NER tagged and find the location!

Is this possible?

I was thinking of creating a regex to extract any information which is tagged as a location, organisation or person and give it to Google and see if it has a latitude and longitude co-ordinatea that corresponds to it.  Or take the 2-3 words in a row that are tagged as NER and add them as an entire address.

I'm just not sure about how I actually give this information to Google!?

Then I'm going to use the Json response to link the text file to the map using the address Google Geocoder matched.

Any insight or ideas would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Geocoding requires address or lat lng for reverse lookup.  So, does your data include addresses or lat lng that you can extract for the lookup?

Comment: @kjy112 my data has locations within it, some are just a city name and some have exact street addresses.  If it only has the city then I would like to put the marker in the centre of the city and if it has the address then obviously put the marker on the street.

Comment: if you have data that are inconsistant it's hard to know if the data is a location or not. furthermore, person's name might be related to a street name which would be erroneous.  Parsing the data would not be a problem. It is the consistancy of the data set.

Comment: @kjy112 The reason I have chosen to use this API is because it's linked directly with google maps so if the location is on google maps then a marker can be placed there.  Even if the address is extremely exact or just a County/City name.  I'm not overly worried about accuracy just about linking the address to a long/lat co-ordinate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JavaScript's Split function](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-string-split.php) to get the data with delimiter being `|` and turn the data into an array.  Let's say if your data is this html format:

```
<p id='data'>Gardai|NNP|O fear|VBP|O a|DT|O 28-year-old|JJ|O man|NN|O ,|,|O missing|VBG|O from|IN|O his|PRP$|O Dublin|NNP|I-PER home|NN|O for|IN|O a|DT|I-DAT week|NN|I-DAT</p>
```

To grab the data w/ delimiter set to `|` you can do the following with JavaScript:

```
function parseDataGeocode() {
    var mydata = document.getElementById('data').innerHTML;
    mydata = mydata.split('|');
    var locationIndexMod = 3; //this determines which element to pull from the array
    for (var i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++) {
        if (i % locationIndexMod == 0) {
            console.log(mydata[i]); //hopefully it's a location
            //do your marker creation after fetch Geocode Lat Lng
            //with mydata[i] as the location/address
        }
    }
}

window.onload = parseDataGeocode;
```

Here is the [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/ejvT7/).  Using firebug on firefox or google chrome's console tool you can see the data output, and if you need help w/ creation of markers and Geocode please let me know.

Comment: That is perfect thanks so much I'm sure I'll have more questions about geocoding I'm a bit of a novice thanks again :-)